# Second order Non-exact ODE by integral factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'v solved the non exact ODE

$$L[u] = xu'' + 2u' + xu = 0$$

by using integral factor sinx

get $$u = \frac{Acosx + Bsinx}{x}$$
where A and B are constant

if

I want to solve $$xu'' + 2u' + xu = exp(x)$$

how can I use the solution of L[u] = 0

thanks..

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation for math formatting hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $L$ is linear in $u$ and you have a particular solution $u_0(x)$ of L[u] = f(x), then the general solution of $L[u] = f(x)$ is $u_0(x) + g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is the general solution of the homogeneous equation $L[u] = 0$. Finding a solution of the the inhomogeneous equation is tricky, but often one can make an educated guess about the form of such a solution, substitute it in the original differential equation and solve for any unknowns.

In our case, $u$ must involve $exp(x)$, because no exponential appears on the LHS. Since there are varying powers of $x$ on the LHS, we know we'll need something more than a simple exponential function, possibly including powers of $x$. (The derivative of a power function is another power function, which could account for the powers of $x$ that occur here.)

So, we might try $u_0(x) = a x^{\lambda} e^x$. Computing $u_0'$ and $u_0''$ and substituting gives an equation in $x$, $\exp x$, and the unknowns $a$ and $\lambda$. Collecting like terms in $x$ and $\exp x$ and solving for each separately, we find that there is indeed a solution of this form, so we can write the general solution as above.

Comment: thanks...I tried this way...
by substituting
$$u=ax^be^x$$
and then get the $$L[u]=e^x$$be
$$x^{b-1} [ab(b-1)+2ab]+x^b [2a-ab] +x^{b+1}[ab+2a]=1$$
it seems unavailable to solve for a and b

Comment: great...I got the particular solution...thanks so much..^^

Comment: by the way ... I notice the particular solution occurs somewhere... So it makes gusse is there another way to get the particular solution ..~~

Answer (score 0):

there is another question....I not sure do I need ask as a new question ..~~

by

I find that when I solve this equation by using integrating factor $$v=sinx$$
the exact form is 
$${\frac{d}{dx}}[xsinx u' + (sinx -xcosx)u]=0$$
integral to get
$$xsinxu'+(sinx-xcosx)u=c_1$$
or
$$u'+({\frac{1}{x}}-{\frac{cosx}{sinx}})u={\frac{c_1}{xsinx}}$$
which has general solution
$$u=e^{-\int({{\frac{1}{x}}-{\frac{cosx}{sinx}}})dx}[\int{e^{\int({{\frac{1}{x}}-{\frac{cosx}{sinx}}})dx}{\frac{c_1}{xsinx}}}dx+c_2]={\frac{c_1cosx + c_2sinx}{x}}$$

when $$L[u]=e^x$$
it has
exact form$$sinxL[u]=sinxe^x$$
with
$${\frac{d}{dx}}[xsinx u' + (sinx -xcosx)u]=sinxe^x$$
integral to get
$$xsinxu'+(sinx-xcosx)u=\int{sinxe^x}={\frac{1}{2}}e^x(sinx - cosx)$$
rearrenge
$$u'+({\frac{1}{x}}-{\frac{cosx}{sinx}})u={\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{e^x}{x}}(1 - \frac{cosx}{sinx})$$
where the particular solution just appears here
$${\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{e^x}{x}}$$
I not sure if it's a special case or general situation...~~?